# TV cartoon show about 3 kids who fight with elemental spirits

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I am trying to remember a television cartoon about kids who had elemental spirits/familiars that were connected to them. One of the main characters was hidden away in this temple area with the ability of fire. Another character had the  earth. When they fought and kids got in a tough spot their elements would evolve and become stronger abilities of fire and earth spirits/familiars. It was not *Gormiti* or *Xiaolin Showdown*.

Comment: This is pretty broad, and borderline unanswerable without more details, as there are dozens of elements-based cartoons/animes; please [edit] in anything that could distingusih this show.

Comment: Like, when did you watch this? In what language? Do you know what network or channel you watched it on? Was the animation cartoony? Realistic? Looked like it was done in another country? Did they have objects they used to summon the familiars? Words? Interpretative dance? What sort of enemies did they face? Did you watch more than one season?

Comment: Also genders, ages, hair colours, distinctive costumes, names, catch phrases or any other distinguishing characteristics of the kids and/or elemental spirits would help.